# Is using the value of assignement just obfuscating or is there any performance benefits?

Tags: c++

For example, is there any difference between :

```
void f(int a, int& b){
    b = a%2;
    if (b!= 0) {
        //do something;
    }
    //do some other things;
}
```

and

```
void f(int a, int& b){
    if ((b = a%2)) {
        //do something;
    }
    //do some other things;
}
```

beyond readability and aesthetics?

My assumptions is that the second one might save a couple cycles but might be considered bad practice, and the first one might be equivalent with a smart enough compiler, but I have no idea really.

Comment: I would be kind of surprised if a compiler didn't produce identical behavior for those snippets.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care. People do that for a couple of reasons. (1) shorten code, or (2) avoid a second call by saving the value where the first call is needed. It doesn't obfuscate -- but it does make things a bit less readable. A good comment explaining what is taking place will cure that.

Comment: In your case, not much different. However, in case you're also _declaring_ the element, it's quite different, as that declaration has a scope limited to the `if` statement. This is useful when to-`bool` check tells if an object is valid - if it's not, it should not be used.

Comment: Performance-wise, this should not result in any differences. I tweaked your snippet a bit (replacing `%2` by an external function call to avoid optimisations), you can see that the assembly generated is identical when enabling optimisations: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/eWfqnExPY

Comment: I agree with the above comments, but I like to do it in two steps because it often makes debugging easier.  In non-optimised code, you can step through the first statement, examine the resulting value, change it maybe (if it's wrong) and then resume execution.  It's harder to do that with a one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much point to it in an `if` statement. But similar style is often used with `while`:

```
while (data = somefunction()) {
    // code
}
```

Splitting this up into separate statements would require something like:

```
while (true) {
    data = somefunction();
    if (!data) {
        break;
    }
    // code
}
```

or

```
data = somefunction() {
while (data) {
    // code
    data = somefunction();
}
```

The first rewrite is significantly more verbose (1 line has become 5), the second requires multiple `data = somefunction()` calls. So the terse version has become idiomatic, and isn't considered obfuscating.

Comment: Alternative to #3 is with `for`: `for (data = somefunction(); data; data = somefunction())`, allowing `continue;` statement.

Comment: @Jarod42 Was going to mention that, but it also requires writing `data = somefunction()` twice.

Comment: Yes, @barmar, I often find myself doing this sort of thing (i.e. #1)

Comment: Not verbose doesn't mean it's idiomatic. Letters of source code are cheap. Your example is also a perfect illustration of when `do while` is justified: `do { data = somefunction(); } while (data);`. That's IMO a much better loop than both your examples.

Comment: @Jarod42 "Allowing continue statement" You say that as if spaghetti programming is a good thing...? The presence of `continue` is almost always a certain indicator of a badly-written loop. And it's also a much worse feature than `goto`, since using `goto` _can_ be justified, but `continue` is intrinsically wrong since it always branches non-conditionally upwards.

Comment: @Lundin: `if (!is_valid(data)) {continue;} do_job(data);` seems not spaghetti code. `if (is_valid(data) {do_job(data);})` increase indentation (So when above code is not just a function but the whole code, the second version doesn't look necessary better).

Comment: @Jarod42 In simple code like that, those 2 versions are very similar and either would be ok. The problem appears when Mr Maintainer strikes: `some_stuff(); if (!is_valid(data)) { continue; } else { some_other_stuff(); } do_job(data);`  Hmm, well didn't they intend `else { some_other_stuff(); do_job(data); }` Hmm or wait why the `else` to begin with. Hmmm... Whereas `some_stuff(); if (is_valid(data)) { some_other_stuff(); do_job(data); }` can pretty much only be written in one single way. Reducing the potential for accidental bugs. The former version has far more wtfs/minute.

Comment: @Lundin: So are you against early `return` too (with only one return statement in function)? `return` and `continue` usage seems similar to me. (I tends to extract loop content in dedicated function with early return).

Comment: @Jarod42 `return` is less problematic since it just ends the function there and then. It doesn't subtly affect execution flow in surrounding parts of the code in the same way as goto/continue/break. Multiple returns could lead to less readable code in some cases, but most of the time it doesn't. My general coding style regarding these (partially based on MISRA C) could be summarised as follows: never use continue, avoid goto and only ever use it to jump downwards, never use multiple breaks in a loop, avoid multiple returns unless it makes the code more readable. Anyway this is off-topic.

Comment: @Lundin "Not verbose doesn't mean it's idiomatic. Letters of source code are cheap." Well here, it seems to be a case of Don't Repeat Yourself. Writing a a single function call is good not because it makes the code shorter, it seems good because it avoids repetition. So if you ever have to change the function call, you only have to do it in one place, with no risk of forgetting the other. Also, do while does not work here once you account for //code.

Answer (score 7):

The performance will be identical.

> beyond readability and aesthetics?

Ignoring performance, then assignment inside expressions is considered dangerous style for a number of other reasons. There is the potential of mix-ups with equality operators and it is making control expressions needlessly brittle by including a side effect inside them.

This is *not* just a style matter, it's a matter of writing needlessly dangerous code on purpose. Most compilers will warn for assignment inside control expressions. The extra parenthesis trick to silence warnings for certain compilers, is not something I would recommend to make a habit of using either. Only use assignment inside control expressions as a last resort.